# Disable nested sorting in dojo enhancedGrid

Tags: dojo

I'm currently trying to disable the nested sorting, as it does not pass the parameters for the nested sort to the store url (only the first sorted column gets passed over). I tried to set "nestedSorting: false" in the grid setup (programmatically), but the sorting is still being showed in the grid headers. Isn't it possible to disable the nested sort?

Answer (score 0):

Please note if DnD is on, nested sorting feature will be turned on automatically, this is a precondition to use DnD, since you need to select and also sort a column - which could only be possible when nested sorting is on. Please see http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid for more details.